# Bison value moving / efficiency

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, bison, move-semantics

I'm working on constructing my parse data structure from bison's semantic values. One particular structure is of type `std::vector<double>`. I'm curious how the bison internals handle moving semantic values. I tried analyzing the c++.m4 file, and found:

```
template <typename Base>
  inline
  void
  ]b4_parser_class_name[::basic_symbol<Base>::move (basic_symbol& s)
  {
    super_type::move(s);
    ]b4_variant_if([b4_symbol_variant([this->type_get ()], [value], [move],
                                      [s.value])],
                   [value = s.value;])[]b4_locations_if([
    location = s.location;])[
  }
```

Unfortunately, I cannot decipher this nearly enough to make out the efficiency of moving a data structure like std::vector, partly owing to my ignorance of the m4 syntax.

Given this in my grammar:

```
%define api.token.constructor
%define api.value.type variant
%type < std::vector<double> > numlist
...
numlist:
    num             { $$ = std::vector<double>(); $$.push_back($1); }
|   numlist "," num { $$ = $1; $$.push_back($3); }
;
```

I am uncertain of the performance implications. Note that this will be compiled with a C++98 compiler and not a C++11 compiler; hence there will be no move semantics.

I'm guessing that the `$$ = std::vector<double>()` statement could be removed; I assume it would be default-constructed already, but I haven't tested and I'm not sure how bison's internal variant type works. What I'm particularly interested in is the `$$ = $1; $$.push_back($3);` Will the vector be copied for every item that is to be added?

I can't determine if this is a case for switching the type to `std::vector<double> *`; admittedly, much of the reasoning behind using bison's variant type was to use plain C++ types instead of a union of pointers.

---

I've also had similar curiosities on a parser that does in fact make use of C++11/14 and in particular `std::unique_ptr`. If one line of a left-recursive rule assigned, say `$$ = std::make_unique<...>(...)`, would the following be able to do `$$ = $1; $$->...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a Bison / Yacc expert but you can have a look at the generated code:

```
      {
  case 2:
#line 20 "test.yy" // lalr1.cc:846
    { yylhs.value.as<  std::vector<double>  > () = std::vector<double>();
      yylhs.value.as<  std::vector<double>  > ().push_back(yystack_[0].value.as< double > ()); }
#line 1306 "test.tab.cc" // lalr1.cc:846
    break;

  case 3:
#line 21 "test.yy" // lalr1.cc:846
    { yylhs.value.as<  std::vector<double>  > () = yystack_[2].value.as<  std::vector<double>  > (); 
      yylhs.value.as<  std::vector<double>  > ().push_back(yystack_[0].value.as< double > ()); }
#line 1312 "test.tab.cc" // lalr1.cc:846
    break;
```

Which lays inside the `parser::parse` method and where `yylhs` is a local variable of type `stack_symbol_type` and `yystack_` is an attribute of the `parser` class of type `stack_type` (which contains `stack_symbol_type`).

It looks like the answer is **yes**, the whole vector will be copied when you do `$$ = $1`, and I don't see how a compiler could optimize this. The declaration of `as` is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
T& as();
```

With a `const` variant, so the affectation is done on the type `T`, which in your case is `std::vector<double>`, and thus a copy is made. Even if you use [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) move semantics, a copy would be made because the RHS is not an `xvalue`.

Comment: Thanks! I really wanted to avoid making the pointer-to-vector construct but it looks like that's the best thing to do.

Comment: @Zac did you consider swapping `$1` and `$$` instead of assigning?

Comment: @Michael I hadn't. Are you referring to std::swap()?

Comment: @Zac I intended to refer to the member function swap Holt cited, but global swap should be overloaded by the standard library to call the member function for vectors, so either way should work.